# Should eglSwapBuffers(...) be blocking until minimal number of video frames is reached?

Tags: ios, egl

I am implementing EGL 1.4 in user space for iOS. The specification for `eglSwapBuffers(...)` states `post the color buffer to a window`.

The specification for `eglSetSwapInterval(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLint interval)` states `The parameter *interval* specifies the minimum number of video frames that are displayed before a buffer swap will occur`.

My questions are:

a) Should `eglSwapBuffers(...)` blocks until the minimal number of frames is reached ?

b) if answer to a) is NO, should `eglSwapBuffers(...)` return without posting the color buffer to the window and return EGL_TRUE.

c) if answer to b) is NO, then what should it be ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be eglSwapBuffers(...) blocks until the minimal number of frames is reached.